# how can I write NSLocalNotification object to sqlite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, nsnotifications

I am using local notification ,i need to update/delete the notification for that I think I have to write object to database so that I can retrieve later then I can delete from the operating system ,so my issue is that how to write object to database any help plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to fetch them from a db there is a method to get an array of all of your notifications

Answer (score 0):

DataType of your notification column is **BLOB** and following code is used to enter data in DB.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification;    
[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:localNotification]
```

And to get it back as notification object use following code.

> NSData *data = **database column value of notification object**;

```
   UILocalNotification *notif = (UILocalNotification*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: hi, please can you explain me to how can store notication in DB ??